SAP Hybris Promotion module: Value is not an instance of string
I am trying to create a custom promotion condition in sap hybris and I am getting an exception "Value is not instance of String" from the class DefaultRuleParameterValueMapperStrategy, I have created a mapper class for customData i.e., Enum(CustomerType) and it saves the value when I provide it through B.O. but gives exception when I refresh the window I get the above mentioned exception.

after saving when I refresh it gives the above mentioned exception, though the mapper is present now what should I do to remove the exception ?


Maybe you can attach your CustomValueMapper class, so others can see the problem?

@Adiputera - Thanks for replying, I found that the customertype was an HybrisEnumValue not the Java Enum that's why it's throwing the error.
